# How to null missing columns when importing CSV

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a very large(200+GB), incorrectly formatted CSV file. Some columns have fewer values than the other columns, i.e.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2
val2,val3
val2,val4,val8,val9
```

Obviously, when I try to import this into postgres it will throw an error about missing data for columns. I would like to avoid fixing this CSV file, as it is very large and will likely take quite a bit of time. How do I get the importer to simply insert null values for the missing data instead of throwing an error?

Comment: You can't, this `val2` is seen as a row with a single column. To get it to work it would need to be `val2,,,,`.

Comment: You could use `awk` to edit the .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk to edit the .csv file.

---

```
#!/bin/sh

cat - <<OMG > omg.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2
val2,val3
val2,val4,val8,val9
OMG

awk -F, '{printf($0); for (i=NF;i<4;i++) {printf(",");} printf("\n"); }' < omg.csv # >out.csv
```

---

Result:

---

```
$ sh awk.sh
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2,,,
val2,val3,,
val2,val4,val8,val9
$
```